# Apache Cassandra connection with spark

Tags: apache-spark

When I execute this expression:

```
Scala> import com.datastax.spark.connector._
```

I receive this error:

> object datastax is not a member of pachage com

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have the cassandra-spark connector library in your classpath. Looks like you are using the spark-shell. Did you follow the documentation? https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/13_spark_shell.md

Comment: it's for ubuntu and i'm using windows 7